# How can I get my muteunmute function to work on the video's overlay element without having the list/content toggle it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The site is a simple landing page with a hero video background that autoplays and when you click the search box(which is in the center of the video) it unmutes and plays the audio from the video. Our mute/unmute button works great but they want the click of the video to also mute/unmute. Whenever I add the element of the `video-overlay` to the function, everything on top of it works as a mute/unmute too which we don't want, it breaks our search tool.

I've tried creating an element specifically for mute/unmute but it still stays on top, I've tried adding different classes to the mute/unmute function (`Hero.onMuteClick`). I looked into `stopPropogation` but I wasn't able to figure that out.

https://jsfiddle.net/kevingsp/9xhzr1by/2/

I expect clicking the `video-overlay` to mute/unmute the audio from the video.

Thanks for reading!

**Edit/Update**
I followed the steps below and it worked, I made the original mute/unmute button unclickable in the CSS with `pointer-events:none;` so the background/overlay could only control it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use focus and focusout.
Take a look at the follwing snippet.

```
init: function() {
  $(".muteunmute").click(function(e) {
      Hero.onMuteClick();
  });
  $('#inputSearch').on('focus',()=>Hero.unmute() ).on('focusout',()=>Hero.mute() );
}
```

**Edit**

Sorry I misunderstood you.

Hope the following snippet fits your needs :)
The problem is that all the elements are children of '.video-overlay', so you have to check which one is the real target.

```
init: function() {
    $(".muteunmute").click(function(e) {
        Hero.onMuteClick();
    });
    $('.video-overlay').click(function(e){
      if($(e.target).hasClass('video-overlay-content'))
      {
            Hero.onMuteClick();
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: Won't my list items toggle the focusout too?

Comment: trying this out now :)

Comment: update: Looks like it worked great! Except it broke the mute button now. It's not clickable, have any suggestions? I do appreciate the help